# How to use GIS in android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, silverlight, gis, arcmap

i need gis map in my project. I know for GIS, i need silver light application in web app.I get an id from arcMap and use this in silver light but there aren't silver light for android.please help me

Comment: Most GIS nowadays don't use Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you you're using ESRI products on the backend.  They have an Android SDK.

https://developers.arcgis.com/android/